# Type-2 errors in the likelihood-ratio/G-test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio, type-i-and-ii-errors

I am quite new to hypothesis testing, and I am currently trying to familiarize myself with the [G-test for independence](http://www.biostathandbook.com/gtestind.html). In my research, I came up with a question for which I could not fit an answer online. In brief: is it possible to compute the probability of making a type-2 error with this test?

---

**Setup**: For the G-test, let $T$ be a table with $n_{\text{row}}$ rows and $n_{\text{col}}$ columns containg counts/entries $T_{i,j}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n_{\text{row}}}\sum_{j=1}^{n_{\text{col}}}T_{i,j} = N$. Assuming a null hypothesis of independence, we can calculate an *expected* table $R$ by summing $T$ along its rows and columns, then forming an outer product and dividing it by $N$:

$$ R = \frac{\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n_{\text{col}}}T_{i,j} \right) \times \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n_{\text{row}}}T_{i,j} \right)}{N} \tag{1}$$

We can then calculate the G-test statistic $s$ as:

$$s(T)=2\sum_{i=1}^{n_{\text{row}}}\sum_{j=1}^{n_{\text{col}}}T_{i,j}\log\left(\frac{T_{i,j}}{R_{i,j}}\right)\tag{2}$$

With $s$, we can derive the $p$-value from the cdf $F$ of a Chi-squared distribution with $d=(n_{\text{row}}-1)(n_{\text{col}}-1)$ degrees of freedom.

$$p(T)=1 - F(s;d)\tag{3}$$

---

**Question**: To my understanding, the null hypothesis of the G-test of independence is, well, independence. As such, the $p$-value relates to the chance of making a Type-1 error (falsely rejecting the null hypothesis $\rightarrow$ falsely assuming dependence between the marginals of $T$, when they are in fact independent). Is there also a way to calculate the chance of making a Type-2 error? (accepting the null hypothesis $\rightarrow$ falsely assuming dependence between the marginals of $T$, when they are in fact dependent)? What information would I require to calculate the Type-2 error?

Comment: Calculating such a value also relates to what kind of deviation you want to be able to detect. If you’ve ever done a power or sample size calculation for a t-test, you’ve seen this in such a setting.

Comment: I am not familiar with this procedure, and will look it up. Can you recommend any resources?

Comment: I like the JBStatistics YouTube channel, and I know he has videos on t-test power and sample size calculations.